# Sharp corners for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

The default EditText widget has rounded corners. How do I change them to sharp / edged corners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw your own 9-patch?

Comment: Redundant question, I knew the answer - still wonder why I asked it? LOL

Comment: Perhaps you were hoping there was a way to do it programmatically.. unfortunately, no :P